# Get target instance for a Style from within a custom MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I'm attempting to use a custom `MyMarkupExtension` within an implicit Style:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{MyMarkupExtension /*some setup*/}" />
</Style>
```

Is it anyhow possible to get the object `MenuItem`, to which the style is applied, or its DataContext from within `ProvideValue` method? Value taken from `IProvideValueTarget.TargetObject` is the Setter.

Comment: have you found a workaround for this issue ?

Comment: It's been some time since I last had access to this code. As far as I remember there is no simple and clean solution, because markup extensions are initialized too early and are then cached, one per many controls. Not as clean as it might be, but depending on purpose, H.B.'s solution could help.

Answer (score 1):

The value will be resolved before it is applied to any control. I would hence recommend you use a [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) (or [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)) with a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx), you can pass in the control using a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) with mode `Self`.